# Complete black in material preview shading tab

Tags: shaders, workspaces

I've just ran into this problem and looked on youtube to find a solution to no avail. I have no idea what I did to make this happen. I'm using blender 2.9 .[image] I don't have any idea what's going on. I'm currently in material preview but in rendered it works fine.

Comment: Hello :). This looks like a GPU drivers issue. Make sure they're up to date, or try different Blender versions.

Comment: Can you upload the blend file?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm sorry I didn't come back I hadn't quite understood this website yet, I'm now going to use it more frequently probably. Sorry I didn't awnser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the material has no shader input. Blender used the default "no shader" and this is simply black.